Верификация Google-аккаунта для организации в России
Я пытаюсь верифицировать Google-аккаунт для моей организации, которая находится в России. Google запросил "Certificate of Incorporation", но я не уверен, какой из наших документов регистрации подходит под их требования.
Я уже предоставил выписку из Единого государственного реестра юридических лиц (ЕГРЮЛ).
Google сообщил, что этого недостаточно. Какие дополнительные документы я могу предоставить?
Кто-нибудь проходил этот процесс верификации для российской организации и может подсказать, какие документы необходимо отправить?

Google сообщил, что этого недостаточно. => Свяжитесь с поддержкой Google. Узнайте, какие конкретно документы им нужны. Тк запросы для документов могут меняться и порой тотально,  лучше уточнить у них напрямую (?)
